# Throwing exceptions in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, .net, exception

Is there a difference between just saying `throw;` and `throw ex;` assuming `ex` is the exception you're catching?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`throw ex;` will erase your stacktrace. Don't do this unless you mean to clear the stacktrace. Just use `throw;`

Comment: I have never seen one, although there might be.
As stated below, I have heard of attaching it to the innerexception, but I can think of no reason you would want to destroy your stack trace.

Answer (score 18):

Here is a simple code snippet that will help illustrate the difference.  The difference being that throw ex will reset the stack trace as if the line "`throw ex;`" were the source of the exception.

Code:

```
using System;

namespace StackOverflowMess
{
    class Program
    {
        static void TestMethod()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                //example showing the output of throw ex
                try
                {
                    TestMethod();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();

            try
            {
                //example showing the output of throw
                try
                {
                    TestMethod();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Output (notice the different stack trace):

> `System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.`
>   `at StackOverflowMess.Program.Main(String[] args) in Program.cs:line 23`
>
> `System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.`
>   `at StackOverflowMess.Program.TestMethod() in Program.cs:line 9`
>   `at StackOverflowMess.Program.Main(String[] args) in Program.cs:line 43`

Answer (score 2):

You have two options throw; or throw the orginal exceptional as an innerexception of a new exception.  Depending on what you need.