# How to intercept the pipeline in an ASP.NET WebAPI?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Is there a way to intercept requests for files like .js, .html, etc in an ASP.NET WebAPI? All methods I tried could only intercept API calls. I need to change the content of js files before sending then to the client or redirect certain calls from one html file to another. I´m not using any Razor or ASP.NET MVC stuff, just plain old html and other content files.

Comment: _intercept requests for files like .js, .html, etc in an ASP.NET WebAPI_ Really ?

Comment: Try this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391130/what-is-an-httphandler-in-asp-net

Comment: and You serve those plain html files using WebAPI?

Comment: @GrzegorzW they are not served using WebAPI (through an api call), they are hosted in the same web application (ASP.NET Web API), but are served as static content.

Comment: @Cybermaxs Really. That is the problem I need to solve now. I know it's not the best way to do it, but it's working as desired now, as long as we don't need to intercept the pipeline. Which now we need.

Comment: @BillGregg I will try to make it work with a custom HTTP Handler. Thanks for the help.

Comment: If anyone else could help with another suggestion, I appreciate.