# Why do some APIs provide mostly interfaces, not classes?

Tags: java, api, class, interface

Some Java APIs provide a large number of interfaces and few classes.  For example, [the Stellent/Oracle UCM API](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E10316_01/ContentIntegration/javadoc/index.html?com/stellent/cis/client/api/scs/component/folder/package-tree.html) is composed of roughly 80% interfaces/20% classes, and many of the classes are just exceptions.

What is the technical reason for preferring interfaces to classes?  Is it just an effort to minimize coupling?  To improve encapsulation/information hiding?  Something else?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90851/is-it-just-me-or-are-interfaces-overused) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/639592/why-are-interfaces-preferred-to-abstract-classes)

Comment: Interesting stuff.  I found the second question earlier, but not the first.  My intent was to find out more about my specific case, but it's definitely good general info.  +1.

Comment: why do some OO languages not even have the equivalent of Java's *class*?  In a clean OO design, the only thing that matter is the abstraction.  Concrete and abstract Java classes are implementation details: people use them because they seek to avoid "code reuse" (not realizing that they can achieve what they think they need to achieve extending Java classes using, say, delegation and composition). Implementation details do **not** exist at the OOA/OOD level. In addition to that, Java interfaces allows multiple inheritance, which matters when doing an OOA/OOD to OOP translation.

Comment: Btw a question like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90851/is-it-just-me-or-are-interfaces-overused just shows how clueless most answerers and upvoters are on SO.  Take SO with a huge grain of salt, for it is not the stronghold of OO-savvy developers ;)

Comment: @Wizard: Interesting-er and interesting-er!  I would like to subscribe to your newsletter, sir.  Could you provide an example of such a class-less language?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It would be to maximize their flexibility in changing the underlying classes behind the scenes.

As long as the interfaces/contracts remain the same, they can change the implementation classes all they want without worrying about affecting people who are using their library.

Answer (score 3):

They are designed for 3rd parties to provide the implementation.

A classic and successful example is [JDBC](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/package-summary.html)  ( 22 interfaces 7 concrete classes )

The idea is to provide a .. well.. programmer interface ( API ) so the clients ( the ones that use the code ) may freely relay on the features these API provides without worrying about the underlying implementation.

Other reason is, there might be an existing provider ( ie. FutureSQL ) which still doesn't exist, but it may implement this interfaces and you'll be able to use it.

Comment: Although a very good reason, it doesn't apply to the OP's example. Stellent isn't built for 3rd party implemenations.

Comment: Well, in this case it would be 3rd party integrations ( the client using the API )  but that's a valid point .

Comment: +1 - DirectX would be another example (even if this doesn't apply directly to the OP's question)

Answer (score 0):

Its likely, the framework/API was developed with [Dependency Injection](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html), extensibility, low coupling and high cohesion in mind

Answer (score 0):

The number of interfaces relative to the number of classes isn't really that important if each class implements a large number of the interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

One of the best example is java.sql package.

The reason is:
when the designer has a clear idea in mind as to what needs to be done and how the entire application [yet to be designed] structured they provide this idea through an API as a bunch of interfaces.

For example:
when SUN (now oracle :-( ) publishes the API for JDBC, the entire SQL package (well most of it) is just interfaces with interoperability very well defined; but the actual vendor of the DB/RDBMS knows what to do so that they achieve the results as expected in the API.

Hence you can write ur java and DB interaction separately while the Database vendor writes the database separately.
The vendor just has to write a driver that meets the API (interfaces) standard with out telling you how he did it.

Yet ur application and the DB interoperate with out any problem [well most of the time ;-)]

it's a long answer but hope this helps.
Thanks,

Ayusman