# type conversion for user defined classes

Tags: java, refactoring

I have a lot of classes which are basically equivalent, ie have almost the same functions in all respect.  Let's call them A and B. There are hundreds of methods that are using A and now due to code changes I have to change them to B.

Is there a way by which I can program a mapping between A and B such that I have minimal code changes?

Comment: It might help if you clarify why you have so many similar classes, and what kind of situations require you to switch from A to B.

Comment: okay the project was written earlier with A and then a better implementation came up and it was just better and easier to manage it with B because a relatively small portion(still in thousands of line of java code) uses A hence we need a way to seamlessly covert between them. with minimal code change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `A` is not `final`, you can make `B extends A`, and have `B`'s methods `@Override` `A`'s. Then wherever previously you were invoking methods on an `instanceof A`, you now provide an `instanceof B`, and let dynamic dispatch handle the rest.

This is called polymorphism. It only works with non-`static` methods having the same exact signature. You can not `@Override` `static` methods.

#### See also

- [Java Tutorials/Object-Oriented Programming Concepts](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/)
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming

#### Related questions

- [Why doesn’t Java allow overriding of static methods ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223386/why-doesnt-java-allow-overriding-of-static-methods)

---

#### On interfaces

Depending on why you were doing this, you should know learn the concept of interfaces and how they're used in object-oriented programming to allow precisely this kinds of flexibility and convenience.

Consider the [`interface List<E>`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html), for example, and an implementation [`ArrayList<E>`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). If you wrote an entire library that works with an `ArrayList<E>`, doing all the usual `add/addAll/remove` etc, and now you must use a `LinkedList<E>` instead, then you'd have little choice but to go to the source code and change all the `ArrayList<E>` to `LinkedList<E>`, and hope that the change doesn't break another code which still assumed that `ArrayList<E>` was used.

If instead your library works with a `List<E>`, then switching to a `LinkedList<E>` need to be done only wherever the objects are created. All the other code that was doing the `add/addAll/remove` would've still worked just fine, since those are methods that are defined in the `interface List<E>` which all implementors will have.

It's not clear from the current context, but if `A` and `B` are so similar, then perhaps they belong to some type `X`. If so, you should consider defining `interface X`, and have `A implements X`, and `B implements X`.

#### See also

- [Java Tutorials/Object-Oriented Programming Concepts/Interfaces](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html)
- *Effective Java 2nd Edition, Item 52: Refer to objects by their interfaces*

#### Related questions

- [Is it just me or are interfaces overused?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90851/is-it-just-me-or-are-interfaces-overused)
- [Why are interfaces preferred to abstract classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639592/why-are-interfaces-preferred-to-abstract-classes)
- [Explaining Interfaces to Students](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3355408/explaining-interfaces-to-students)

Answer (score 2):

You should define an interface that both A and B implement.

Comment: +1.  First make A implement (let's call it) I.  Now make every caller take, instead of an A, an I.  Your program behavior is unchanged at this point.  Now, as needed, you can make B implement I and pass B's in, testing as you go.  This is cleaner than the subclass options others have suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you should probably use inheritance in this case.

If you make `B` a subclass of `A`, you can use `B` wherever you had been using `A` without changing any of the code.

Sun/Oracle has [some great tutorials on inheritance](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) that you may want to take a look at in order to get started.

Answer (score 1):

You can make A an [adapter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) for B. I.e.

```
class A {
   private B b = new B();

   public String someMethod() {
      return b.equivalentSomeMethod();
   }
}
```

That's in case the methods are *similar*, and not *exactly the same*. If they are exactly the same - use your IDE to get rid of one of the classes and replace it with the other.

Comment: Is there any reason this would be preferred over setting up some inheritance relationship?

Comment: yes - I added a comment about that. In case the methods differ in some ways (which was my initial impression)

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways, each with advantages and disadvantages. A couple ideas:

Make B a subtype of A. Then you can pass instances of B to methods requiring A. Alternatively, extract a common interface, and replace uses of A with that interface where possible (a good IDE can do this automatically).

In A, include the following constructor:

```
A(B b) {
    // create an A with the data from b
}
```

or create an Adapter that subclasses A and delegates all calls to B.

In any case, if minimizing tedium in changing the code is your objective, look into your IDE's refactoring operations.

Comment: +1 for naming *both* solutions, both have their uses and we can't recommend one without more details.