# What's the difference between an interface and an abstract class?

Tags: oop, interface, abstract-class

#### Duplicate:

> [When to use an interface instead of an abstract class and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479142/when-to-use-an-interface-instead-of-an-abstract-class-and-vice-versa)

Probably one of the most famous software developer job interview questions.

What would be your answer?

**EDIT:** I'm trying to find out how you would answer this in a real-life situation. Please try to formulate your answer as you would on a real job interview (be complete, but don't be too long, post no links of course).

Comment: I don't want to sound like the members of the local question-closing militia but this has been discussed over and over eleventy billion times here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/479142/when-to-use-an-interface-instead-of-an-abstract-class-and-vice-versa

Comment: Totally agree; asked many times before.

Comment: Well, this question is about "what's the difference", while that other one is "when would you use one or the other" - that's different enough IMHO to warrant its own question...

Comment: @DevSolar: slight variations of this question appear many times, not just that one quoted...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56867/interface-vs-base-class

Comment: After some searching I still don't think this should have been closed. Lots of Q's about when to use one or the other, but I did *not* find one merely aiming at the syntactical difference.

Comment: "Syntactical difference?"  The OP mentions that this is a common interview question.  During an interview, the interviewer is probably more interested in design issues than syntax.

Comment: I should have been more to the point in the original post, I just added my edit. My intent was to try to find the best answer to this interview question.

Answer (score 7):

An interface only describes the actual signature of its methods etc. Any class implementing that interface must then provide an explicit implementation.

An abstract class can contain a partial implementation of its methods etc.

Answer (score 2):

An abstract class can have member variables, an interface cannot (or, in C++, *should* not).

In Java, an "Interface" is a well-defined syntactical element, while in C++ it's merely a design pattern.

Comment: The answer was given as a "answer right now" response. It's not exhaustive, I know, but it's what I came up with ad hoc.

Answer (score 2):

Interfaces provide definitions of methods that must be implemented by a class. The purpose of interfaces is to allow you to generalise specific functionality regardless of implementation. You may have an `IDatabase` interface that has an `Open`/`Close` method. The class that implements that interface may be connecting to a MySQL database or MS Access database. Irrespective of *how* it accomplishes this task, the goal is still the same...Open database, close database.

Abstract classes are base classes that contain some abstract methods. They cannot be instantiated they are to be derived from. The purpose of an Abstract class is to allow you to define some generic functionality and sub-class to implement more specific functionality where appropriate.

So in summary, you should use interfaces when the implementation of each class differs completely. Use abstract classes when you have some similar behaviour but need to implement parts differently.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the difference is language dependent, but that in C++ at least, abstract classes are the means by which interfaces are implemented.

Answer (score 0):

As far as job interviews are concerned, I've always heard that the key point is that an interface is a contract; an interface, while not implementing it itself, guarantees functionality.