# Abstract classes vs interfaces to represent a family

Tags: oop

Abstract classes are described as being useful for a family of objects (e.g. could be used for animals which are mammals). However, what difference is there between using an interface or abstract class for representing a family of related objects?

My process is to use an abstract class when I want to define common functionality but with the option for future extensions and an interface for custom functionality (implementations).

For example, I wrote an abstract class to encapsulate some database functionality which will be used heavily in a small web app at work. I wrote an abstract class with virtual methods which can be overrided with custom functionality in the future (e.g. logging, or some reporting of the database events which may be required).

Is this the right way to go? Is there any significance in choosing one construct (abstract or interface) to represent a family?

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56867/interface-vs-base-class answer this question ? If yes.. dupe.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When to use an interface instead of an abstract class and vice versa?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/479142/when-to-use-an-interface-instead-of-an-abstract-class-and-vice-versa)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An abstract class should be used when there is common state and behavior between all types.  An interface should be used when all types will have a common interface but will not share state or behavior.

***Here is an example.***

> German Shepherd, Golden Retriever, Beagle

These three objects are all dogs, and as such they share certain common state (carnivorous, 4 legs, etc.) and they also share certain overridable behavior (bark, pant, etc.).  In this instance it would make the most sense to create an abstract Dog class to hold this common state and behavior and create subtypes of Dog for each type of dog.

> Pencil, Pen, Chalk

These objects have no common state and they cannot share behavior.  Yet you may notice that they do have something in common - they are cabaple of *writing*.  These objects are best build separately and without a base class and then tied together with a `Writable` interface that exposes each type's `Write` method.

Comment: Pretty much the way I decide. But I take it then they are both suitable for representing families, as long as I abide by the guideline you've given.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using interfaces so that you can implement new functionality in your database utility at some future point.

As always, the primary design principle when it comes to development is

**Design towards an interface, not an implementation**

Answer (score 0):

With abstract classes, you can provide implementation that is needed and shared by all the classes in your hierarchy. Therefore, you're reusing code. You may allow the derived classes to override the default behavior or not but at least you're providing a baseline functionality like breathing for a new born animal. However, with interfaces, you can't provide any implementation. You simply define a contract that all classes that inherits that interface should honor and provide implementation for. This may lead to repetitive and duplicate code among the hierarchy of classes.

Interfaces are not very good for extensibility and you need to worry about versioning. You decide to make change to an existing interface but you will soon realize that there are a lot of classes in existence you may need to modify. Think about adding Breath method to IMammal interface that's already being used by many mammals. You will need to go and provide Breath implementation for each one. With an abstract class, you can simply add Breath method and provide some baseline implementation without having to worry about existing derived classes. So abstract classes are more flexible in term of the development of your hierarchy and the api.