# Interface and abstract public function

Tags: php, interface, abstract-function

It seems to me that both `interface` and `abstract function` are quite similar,

it's like an order that some method must be implemented,

so what's the difference?

Comment: Duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221512/abstract-class-and-interface-class

Comment: Another duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/761194/interface-vs-abstract-class-general-oo

Comment: Sorry,it's a **typo**,I mean `abstract function`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**[Have a look at this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913098/php-what-is-the-difference-between-an-interface-and-abstract-class)**

**Quoting:** (Very Good Explantion by e-satis)

**Interface**

An interface is a contract: the guy writing the interface say "hey, I accept things looking that way", and the guy using the interface say "OK, the class I write looks that way".

*And interface is an empty shell*, there are only the signatures (name / params / return type) of the methods. The methods do not contain anything. The interface can't do anything. It's just a pattern.

E.G (pseudo code):

```
// I say all motor vehicles should look like that :
interface MotorVehicle
{
    void run();

    int getFuel();
}

// my team mate complies and write vehicle looking that way
class Car implements MotoVehicle
{

    int fuel;

    void run()
    {
        print("Wrroooooooom");
    }


    int getFuel()
    {
        return this.fuel;
    }
}
```

Implementing an interface consume very little CPU, because it's not a class, just a bunch of names, and therefor there is no expensive lookup to do. It's great when it matters such as in embedded devices.

**Abstract classes**

Abstract classes, unlike interfaces, are classes. There are more expensive to use because there is a lookup to do when you inherit from them.

Abstract classes look a lot like interfaces, but they have something more : you can define a behavior for them. It's more about a guy saying "these classes should look like that, and they got that in common, so fill in the blanks !".

e.g:

```
// I say all motor vehicles should look like that :
abstract class MotorVehicle
{

    int fuel;

    // they ALL have fuel, so why let others implement that ?
    // let's make it for everybody
    int getFuel()
    {
         return this.fuel;
    }

    // that can be very different, force them to provide their
    // implementation
    abstract void run();


}

// my team mate complies and write vehicle looking that way
class Car extends MotorVehicule
{
    void run()
    {
        print("Wrroooooooom");
    }
}
```

By: https://stackoverflow.com/users/9951/e-satis

Answer (score 1):

In languages without multiple inheritance, the difference is quite important. In php or Java terms, a class might implement several interfaces, but can only inherit from a single parent class, which may be abstract.

In c++ for example, the distinction becomes less important.