# Whats the need for abstract class and interface in Java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Abstract class and Interface class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221512/abstract-class-and-interface-class)

Whats the need for abstract class and interface in Java

Answer (score 0):

Abstract class can have some implementation but interfaces are pure contract specifications with no implementation. Also a class can extend only one class(abstract or not) but can implement any number of interfaces.