# Abstract and Interface in java

Tags: java, class, interface, abstract

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Interface vs Abstract Class (general OO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761194/interface-vs-abstract-class-general-oo)
>   [When to use abstract class or interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221512/when-to-use-abstract-class-or-interface)

Can you provided implementations on a abstract class?

what's the difference between these two?

and when will I know when will I know to use them?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html. Maybe you have any concrete questions?

Comment: Good starting point - [Interfaces and Inheritance](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/index.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This pages gives a good comparison: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html . You could have found it with a very quick google search.

Answer (score 1):

`Interface` is used for defining a contract. Abstract classes are used for defining some methods which are common to all descendants and possibly some methods which will differ(they will be `abstract`). With `interfaces` or `abstract classes` polymorphism is reached.