# When to use interfaces or abstract classes? When to use both?

Tags: oop, interface, abstract-class

While certain guidelines state that you should use an interface when you want to define a contract for a class where inheritance is not clear (`IDomesticated`) and inheritance when the class is an extension of another (`Cat : Mammal`, `Snake : Reptile`), there are cases when (in my opinion) these guidelines enter a gray area.

For example, say my implementation was `Cat : Pet`. `Pet` is an abstract class. Should that be expanded to `Cat : Mammal, IDomesticated` where `Mammal` is an abstract class and `IDomesticated` is an interface? Or am I in conflict with the [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)/[YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAGNI) principles (even though I'm not sure whether there will be a `Wolf` class in the future, which would not be able to inherit from `Pet`)?

Moving away from the metaphorical `Cat`s and `Pet`s, let's say I have some classes that represent sources for incoming data. They all need to implement the same base somehow. I could implement some generic code in an abstract `Source` class and inherit from it. I could also just make an `ISource` interface (which feels more "right" to me) and re-implement the generic code in each class (which is less intuitive). Finally, I could "have the cake and eat it" by making both the abstract class and the interface. What's best?

These two cases bring up points for using only an abstract class, only an interface and using both an abstract class and an interface. Are these all valid choices, or are there "rules" for when one should be used over another?

---

I'd like to clarify that by "using both an abstract class and an interface" that includes the case when they essentially represent the same thing (`Source` and `ISource` both have the same members), but the class adds generic functionality while the interface specifies the contract.

Also worth noting is that this question is mostly for languages that do not support multiple inheritance (such as .NET and Java).

Comment: I'd like to note that I did see several "Interface vs. Abstract classes" questions, but in this question, I'm most of all interested in when to use *both* interfaces and abstract classes (if this is a valid thing to do.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Interface vs Abstract Class (general OO)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/761194/interface-vs-abstract-class-general-oo)

Comment: possible duplicate of [When to use an interface instead of an abstract class and vice versa?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/479142/when-to-use-an-interface-instead-of-an-abstract-class-and-vice-versa)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

As a first rule of thumb, I prefer abstract classes over interfaces, [based on the .NET Design Guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229013(v=vs.100).aspx). The reasoning applies much wider than .NET, but is better explained in the book [Framework Design Guidelines](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321246756).

The main reasoning behind the preference for abstract base classes is versioning, because you can always add a new virtual member to an abstract base class without breaking existing clients. That's not possible with interfaces.

There are scenarios where an interface is still the correct choice (particularly when you don't care about versioning), but being aware of the advantages and disadvantages enables you to make the correct decision.

So as a partial answer before I continue: Having both an interface and a base class only makes sense if you decide to code against an interface in the first place. If you allow an interface, you must code against that interface only, since otherwise you would be violating the Liskov Substitution Principle. In other words, even if you provide a base class that implements the interface, you cannot let your code consume that base class.

If you decide to code against a base class, having an interface makes no sense.

If you decide to code against an interface, having a base class that provides default functionality is optional. It is not necessary, but may speed up things for implementers, so you can provide one as a courtesy.

An example that springs to mind is in ASP.NET MVC. The request pipeline works on IController, but there's a Controller base class that you typically use to implement behavior.

Final answer: If using an abstract base class, use only that. If using an interface, a base class is an optional courtesy to implementers.

---

**Update:** I *no longer* prefer abstract classes over interfaces, and I haven't for a long time; instead, I favour composition over inheritance, using SOLID as a guideline.

(While I could edit the above text directly, it would radically change the nature of the post, and since a few people have found it valuable enough to up-vote it, I'd rather let the original text stand, and instead add this note. The latter part of the post is still meaningful, so it would be a shame to delete it, too.)

Comment: Ah thanks for the useful tips! I feel that interfaces are said to be "good practice" (and thus I try to find uses for them) but in practice they don't really solve that many problems, at least not in small- to medium-sized projects... I believe I'll try to stick with abstract base classes in my next project unless I find a particular good reason for going with an interface.

Comment: Define an interface and an abstract class implementing it. Then most implementations can just extend the abstract class without versioning issues (new methods can be added to the interface and the abstract class), while if that' s not possible (e.g. when there's already another super) an implementation can just implement the interface.

Comment: With JDK8 and default methods for interfaces the versioning argument appears even less relevant now. Nevertheless an interesting distinction to think about.

Comment: The first link is (effectively) broken (*"This topic is no longer available"*).

Answer (score 20):

I tend to use base classes (abstract or not) to describe what something *is*, while I use interfaces to describe the *capabilities* of an object.

A Cat *is a* Mammal but one of it's *capabilities* is that it is Pettable.

Or, to put it a different way, classes are nouns, while interfaces map closer to adjectives.

Answer (score 12):

From MSDN, [Recommendations for Abstract Classes vs. Interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scsyfw1d%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> - If you anticipate creating multiple versions of your component, create an abstract class. Abstract classes provide a simple and easy way to version your components. By updating the base class, all inheriting classes are automatically updated with the change. Interfaces, on the other hand, cannot be changed once created. If a new version of an interface is required, you must create a whole new interface.
> - If the functionality you are creating will be useful across a wide range of disparate objects, use an interface. Abstract classes should be used primarily for objects that are closely related, whereas interfaces are best suited for providing common functionality to unrelated classes.
> - If you are designing small, concise bits of functionality, use interfaces. If you are designing large functional units, use an abstract class.
> - If you want to provide common, implemented functionality among all implementations of your component, use an abstract class. Abstract classes allow you to partially implement your class, whereas interfaces contain no implementation for any members.

Answer (score 2):

I always use these guidelines:

- Use interfaces for multiple TYPE inheritance (as .NET/Java don't use multiple inheritance)
- Use abstract classes for a re-usable implementation of a type

The rule of the dominant concern dictates that a class always has a main concern and 0 or more others (see http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/tarr99degrees.html). Those 0 or more others you then implement through interfaces, as the class then implements all the types it has to implement (its own, and all interfaces it implements).

In a world of multiple implementation inheritance (e.g. C++/Eiffel), one would inherit from classes which implement the interfaces. (In theory. In practise it might not work that well.)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to provide the option of replacing your implementation completely, use an interface. This applies especially for interactions between major components, these should always be decoupled by interfaces.

There may also be technical reasons for prefering an interface, for example to enable mocking in unit tests.

Internally in a component it may be fine to just use an abstract class directly to access a hierarchy of classes.

If you use an interface and have a hierarchy of implementing classes then it is good practice to have an abstract classe which contain the common parts of the implementation. E.g.

```
interface Foo
abstract class FooBase implements Foo
class FunnyFoo extends FooBase
class SeriousFoo extends FooBase
```

You could also have more abstract classes inheriting from each other for a more complicated hierarchy.

Answer (score 2):

There is also something called the [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle - Don't Repeat Yourself.

In your example of data sources you say there is some generic code that is common between different implementations. To me it seems that the best way to handle that would be to have an abstract class with the generic code in it and some concrete classes extending it.

The advantage is that every bug fix in generic code benefits all concrete implementations.

If you go interface only you will have to maintain several copies of the same code which is asking for trouble.

Regarding abstract + interface if there is no immediate justification for it I would not do it. Extracting interface from abstract class is an easy refactoring, so I would do it only when it is actually needed.

Comment: Most scenarios where you have an interface will not result in "several copies of the same code".

Comment: In this specific scenario according to OP he has some common code. If you use interfaces you can still have it in one places using some delegation, but I wouldn't bother.

Answer (score 2):

Refer to below SE question for generic guidelines:

[Interface vs Abstract Class (general OO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761194/interface-vs-abstract-class-general-oo/33963650#33963650)

**Practical use case for interface:**

1. Implementation of [Strategy_pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern): Define your strategy as an interface. Switch the implementation dynamically with one of concrete implementations of strategy at run time.
2. Define a **capability** among multiple unrelated classes.

**Practical use case for abstract class:**

1. Implementation of [Template_method_pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern): Define a skeleton of an algorithm. The child classes can't change strucutre of the algortihm but they can re-define a part of the implementation in child classes.
2. When you want share non-static and non-final variables among multiple related classes with  "**has a**" relation.

**Use of both abstradt class and interface:**

If you are going for an abstract class, you can move abstract methods to interface and abstract class can simply implement that interface. All use cases of abstract classes can fall into this category.