# Does anybody recognize any pattern/antipattern in attached class diagram?

Tags: java, design-patterns, oop, anti-patterns

[alt text http://img8.imageshack.us/img8/8558/classdiagram.png](http://img8.imageshack.us/img8/8558/classdiagram.png)

Short description: I have a doubt whether it's normal that `AbstractCrudDaoImpl` implements both interface and abstract class which are inherited from the same parent (`ReadOnlyDao`).

Comment: Please give us the method signatures for `ReadOnlyDao` and `CrudDao`.

Comment: I have standard CRUD methods. In ReadOnly branch I have _findAll()_ and _findById()_ methods. In Crud-branch I have _create()_, _update()_ and _delete()_ methods.

Comment: Unrelated question but what do you use for drawing your class diagram? I know of some software but it appears unfamiliar.

Comment: Also, the naming applied to the classes reminds me of the builder pattern but this diagram looks impractical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have some special method defined in `AbsractReadOnlyDaoImpl` which is not in the `ReadOnlyDao` interface, that specific inheritance is pretty much useless.

Otherwise, looks fine.

Comment: ReadOnlyDao has methods which are common to _all_ concrete implementations. AbstractReadOnlyDaoImpl implements them. AbstractCrudDaoImpl inherits these implementations and thus I avoid "copy and paste programming". Why "that specific inheritance" useless?

Comment: Ah, I see what u probably meant. You says about CrudDao extends ReadOnlyDao and that's odd inheritance. You are probably right, I'll think about it.

Answer (score 2):

I would take exception to the name **ReadOnlyDao** - it implies that anything that implements it is also read only, which is clearly untrue.

I suggest changing it to **ReadableDao**.  Ditto for **AbstractReadableDaoImpl**.

Comment: Nice suggestion, I didn't like ReadOnlyDao name too.

Answer (score 1):

You could split this question into two:

- Is it normal and meaningful to have one inteface that derives from another interface?
- Is it normal to have both an abstract class and an interface that models the same concept?

The first question is easy to answer: yes, this makes sense in situations where you have some classes that only requires the 'core' interface, but other classes that deal with the richer interface.

The other question I've previously dealt with [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231985/when-to-use-interfaces-or-abstract-classes-when-to-use-both/1232759#1232759).

Answer (score 1):

The design seems very reasonable to me.

By looking at your class diagram, I was able to get a clear idea about each participant. I think that's a good sign - it means there's a clear separation of roles.

The fact that `CrudDao` extends `ReadOnlyDao` makes perfect sense to me. Read-write operations are a superset of read-only operations; if you can do something with a read-only interface, you should be able to do it with a read-write interface as well - which is exactly what inheritance achieves.

Answer (score 1):

seems weird. Should CrudDao access ReadOnlyDao instead of AbstractReadOnlyDao? At first it seemed weird AbstractReadOnlyDao is accessing AbstractReadOnlyDaoImpl but on second look it seems ok.