# What's the best way to define the words "class" and "object" to someone who hasn't used them?

Tags: java, oop, terminology

My neighbor is taking "Intro to Java", and asked me to help explain a few of the first-day concepts.  I realized that since I do this everyday, I don't have the beginner's mind, and it's hard to relate some of this stuff from scratch.

The one that's actually not trivial for me to explain is "what the heck is a class?"

Best I have so far:

- A **variable** holds some kind of data; one variable might be a first name, another variable might be your weight in pounds.
- A **method** is a function, it does stuff, and can do stuff with those variables.   A method might display your name on screen, or tell you how much weight you should lose to have a good BMI ratio.
- An **object** holds both variables and methods; one object might represent you, a second object might represent me.
- A **class** is kind of the blueprint or template that describes the methods and variables that will be in each object.  An object is an instantiated (instance of a) class; an object is something, while the class is simply the plans to make that something.

Continuing the example, we have a Person object, which is instantiated to hold Alice's data, and another Person object instantiated to hold Bob's data, and another for Carol, and so on.

How do I tune this example to make more sense, and/or what's a better approach?  The word "instantiated" feels too heavy at this point.

(I think this is a useful question, but is obviously subjective; marked as community wiki.)

Comment: Maybe it's best not to mention that Object is a Class...

Comment: Or that a class definition can be an object.

Comment: Maybe if you say that "instance" means "example" things go easier. Either, the best way to learn is by putting it in pratice with exercises. I recommend get some from a good Java book.

Comment: Actually, your's is a lot better description than most I've seen - you make the distinction between the software constructs instantiated to refer to things and the real-world things they refer too. If you try and go down the Man/Woman extends Person route, you end up with an ontology rather than a coherent set of objects sending messages to each other to perform a function by the concert of their activities.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323330/difference-between-object-and-instance and other postings.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

A class and some class instances:

[image: Courtesy of wikipedia]

*([public domain image hosted by wikipedia](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/wiki/File:Motlle_crespellines.jpg))*

Comment: I like this! Fantastic explanation!

Comment: Okay, this is one that's going to the neighbor.

Answer (score 24):

> Class : Object :: Blueprint : Building

Comment: you mean `Class : Object :: Blueprint : Building`

Answer (score 13):

"Car" is a class. *My* car, sitting in my driveway, is an instance (object).

Answer (score 3):

One of the examples I use during my java courses is the `Human` *class*.

Everyone reading this is a `Human` (I least I hope so !), we all have our differences our resemblances but at the end we're all `Human` (After all).

Each `Human` (known as an *instance* or *object*) has specific characteristics such as the eyes color or the voice which are the *fields* (you called that *variables*, but the right name would be *fields*). But the values are different from an `Human` *instance* to another.

There is also a common knowledge, shared with the humanity, principles like the "Pythagorean theorem". This knowledge is common, it can be interpreted as a *static field* (I know it's an exaggeration) which means that this knowledge is not only contained in one human but in the humanity.

Every `Human` can do things such as walking, speaking etc. this is known as *method*, walking is the same for everyone, but when I walk, not everyone walk. The act of walking only affects the `Human` *instance* which does this, but still it's defined by the `Human` *class*

---

If you want to get deeper in OOP, [Teaching OOP to non-programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538275/teaching-oop-to-non-programmers/3538297#3538297)

Answer (score 3):

An object is a *thing*. A class is a *category* of things.

"Person" is a class; you are an object, an instance of the Person class. Also, the word "you" can be thought of as a variable, since it refers to a Person, but not always the same Person.

Answer (score 3):

Object Oriented programming is about creating programs using as building blocks, "things" that exists in the real world, these real world things are called objects, hence object *oriented*

For instance, if you're creating a Address Book program, you may define the following objects:

```
person, address, phone
```

Among many, many others. Those would be real life objects, and you describe your program in terms of these abstractions.

With that in mind you can start describing some concepts.

**Class** is used to define the characteristics an objects will have. A class is used only as a template, or a blueprint. For instance, for all the persons in your address book, you may say they all will have:

```
Person:
   - name 
   - last name 
   - phone number 
   - address
```

Etc.

An address may have:

```
 Address:
    - street 
    - number
    - city 
    - zip code 
    - country
```

And so on. As you can notice, a class me be defined in terms of other classes, for instance,  in this context, a person has one address.

An **Object** is a particular instance of a given class. When you add an entry to your address book, you create an object and fill in the attributes.

```
 onePerson  ofType Person is (  
     - name = "Oscar"
     - last name = "Reyes" 
     - phone number = "56 58 11 11"
     - address = anAddress ofType Address (
                     - street = "Tecolotes" 
                     - number = 32
                     - city   = "D.F." 
                     - zip code = 23423
                     - country = "Mexico"
                 ) 
  )
```

So, this object is a class instantiated with data. Other entry in the address book are other objects with different data.

That shows the difference between them.

There are other relevant concepts in OOP that are worth listing, and interrelate with the concept of object and class:

**Abstraction**  You don't need to list all the attributes of a person, to use it. for instance, in this case, you don't care if that person is single or married, even when in real life, persons are either single or married.

**Encapsulation** Attributes from the person are hidden to other objects and are accessed through methods, this prevent from data corruption.

**Polymorphism** A different type may  respond differently to the same message or method.

**Inheritance** classes may have subclasses and attributes and behavior which inherit the characteristics of the super classes.

Comment: Can you explain abstraction a little more ?

Comment: And i do not understand the meaning of this statement "So, this object a class instance with data" ?

Comment: It is better Now.

Answer (score 3):

A class description is like a blueprint for a house. All the houses built from that blueprint are objects of that class. A given house is an instance. A tenant can be a changing variable in the house. An example of a method is the procedure by which the post office sends and receives messages (mail) to the house via its mailbox.

Answer (score 2):

class == cookie cutter, object == cookie.

Comment: Nope, I disagree.  The class specifies methods and attributes for all its instances.

Comment: class = cookie maker. But the class=blueprint is still better. A building blueprint stands for a class as the building stands for an object.

Comment: @duffymo, you beat me to it.  This explanation works well for CS/OO civilians.

Comment: I think a better analogy is class == recipe, object == cookie.

Comment: Cookies are tastier.  I think they resonate better with non-programmers.  8)  Recipe might work, but I was trying to be pithy and fast.

Comment: class : cake recipe :: object : chocolate cake warm from the oven

Comment: Mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm - chocolate cake warm from the oven.

Comment: But cookie cutter do not list methods to use on cookie ?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Wouldn't Better Analogy be Human Beings  as a class , me and you as an object.

Comment: Nobody cares.  This question is six years old.

Answer (score 2):

class:: Man or Woman

object:: me, you ...

Answer (score 2):

A **class** is a blueprint/template which you use to create objects. An **object** is an instance of a class.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If and only if he is familiar with Plato's Theory of Forms, you can make an analogy where classes are like Plato's forms and objects are like Plato's real world objects.

See [this post](http://www.richardfarrar.com/plato-and-object-oriented-programming/) for a full description.

Answer (score 1):

Class: Girl

Object : that girl, this girl, my girl...umm maybe not.

Yea all girls should have the properties of a Girl (class in this case).

Answer (score 1):

I always define them as blueprint and product.

A blueprint describes the complete product in every detail, the product is the result that comes out of the machine.

Answer (score 1):

If your neighbor is into classical philosophy, classes are Plato's Forms and objects are the things we see everyday that are based on the Forms.

Answer (score 1):

Class can be defined as the blue print or template which defines attributes,actions,states for the entity and Object would be the one which would be implementation for the entity.

Answer (score 1):

A java class is the structure or blueprint of an object and object is the instance(memory creation) of a class.

Example: Car is an object(real world entity).
firstly, make the structure or design of a Car it's class and when the design of car, to convert real world Car it's an Object. the Car(object) is working now base behalf of design of a car(class).

Answer (score 0):

Panda DNA is a class. A Panda running around, eating and performing Panda-like activities is an object.

Comment: That analogy doesn't really make a lot of sense. A class is not just just the code of its constructor, which is the closest thing DNA maps to.

Answer (score 0):

If they are learning to program OO have them use [BlueJ](http://www.bluej.org/download/download.html).  They should get the differences after walking through the first tutorial.

You define the classes and when you instantiate them they actually appear at the bottom of the GUI at which point you can call methods on them.

It really helps get the point through better than any analogy you want to try.  Even if you nail the analogy, it doesn't translate into code for someone who hasn't learned OO yet (even though for all of us it seems really natural and all these descriptions make great sense.)

Answer (score 0):

OOP is just one more way of representing Abstract Data Structures in programs. In object-oriented terminology, the type is called a class, and the variable with that type is called an object. More on [type <-> class, variable <-> object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1692933/what-is-an-abstract-data-type-in-object-oriented-programming/1693383#1693383) correspondence.

Comment: True, but irrelevant. We're talking about explaining these concepts to an absolute beginner, not to someone who's moving from C to Java.

Comment: Explaining OOP to an absolute beginner is nonsense anyway. Everything is good in its season.

Comment: And by the way do you really think that all this cookies/cars/blueprints/whatever examples really explains something? "Surely You're Joking, Mr. Feynman!" =)

Comment: @Wildcat They Explain To Beginner so that they do not get too tense reading all info and decide to leave it all together , also the above answer by OscarRyz is awesome for explaining deep and clear.

Answer (score 0):

You might find this talk by Guy L. Steele interesting:  http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=-8860158196198824415#

Answer (score 0):

Object is an instance of a class
Variable is an instance of a type

That given,a class can be something like "type on steroids":
   it can have :
        variables which can be from any type or objects from another class
        methods,which 
            can operate on class variables in the same way as different types have their methods(for example `+(bool,bool)`)
            can have access to the class variables 
    and it's all defined by yourself!

You can use the classes to model a problem in the optimal way.
But there are sometimes other ways to do it ;)(not only OOP)

Answer (score 0):

class: custom variable type

object: a variable, whose type is custom defined (if you don't count the built-in ones)

Answer (score 0):

We can also understand the concept of class and object as:
as a class is a template so lets have following two examples:
Example 1: a recipe of a cake is a template so its a class and cakes that are made 
following recipe are the objects.
Example 2: A brick maker is a class and bricks are objects

Answer (score 0):

Your question details have pretty good definitions of all the terms. Here's an analogy I found pretty useful - I've listed it in a kind of top-down approach:

**class** *Employee*. This is a kind of, as you say, 'blueprint' or 'template' that contains generic details about *all* kinds of employees in an organization - let's consider the *director*, a *project manager*, a *developer*, a *contractor*, or a member of the *housekeeping* staff. They're all employees : hence, they're all *instances* of the class, or **objects**.

All the objects have certain *attributes* in common -
they're all allotted, say, an *employee ID*. They all draw a *salary*. They all have a *designation*. One could call these the **member variables**, as they exist for all objects, but their values are clearly different based on what object they're members of.

And finally, there are some **functions** that need to be performed for all employees - say *onBoarding()* or *calculateSalary()*.

Answer (score 0):

```
Class: Human being
Object : Man, Woman 

Class : Fruit 
Object : Apple, Banana, Mango ...

Class : Mobile Phone
Object : Apple , Samsung , LG ...

Class : Food
Object : Pizza, Rice ....
```

Answer (score 0):

An Object is a group of related data and functionality. What the group of data and functionality will consist of is defined in the class. Class is the design or specification of the object.

Answer (score 0):

Class teaches Objects how to behave. 
A class is a blueprint for an object. It tells the virtual machine how to make an object of that particular type. Each object made from that class can have it’s own values for the instance variables of that class.
Example: You might use the Button class to make dozens of different buttons, and each button might have it’s own color, size , shape , functionality.

Answer (score -1):

I would highly recommend telling him/her to buy a copy of a book called [The Object-Oriented Thought Process](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672330164) by Matt Weisfeld. It's a really good conceptual introduction to OO. I've lent out my copy to a few people who were just getting into OO and they really liked it.

Comment: I just finished "The Object-Oriented Thought Process" fourth edition and was deeply disappointed. It explains OO concepts quite superficially which makes them harder to understand. Also it's full of outdated advice (the book calls XML the state of the art of serialization and recommends passing around `null`). And although it's the fourth edition of the book, the code samples are riddled with errors, way beyond typos. I wouldn't recommend this book at all.

Answer (score -1):

I can say with an example: Animal, Human, car etc. Here Animal, Human, car considered as Class, Now consider Dog: Here Dog considered as Object, who is under Animal class. If we consider a dog, then its state are - name, breed, color, and the behavior are - barking,Eating, running, Sleeping. Now we can say, A class is a blue print of Animal class from which individual object is created. Here barking(), running(), eating(),Sleeping() etc. are method of the particular Dog object. I think it will be little easier to understand the difference between Class and object.

Comment: It's wrong. Animal and Human are in your example indeed classes but abstract ones and the Dog would be a concrete class. Dog might be both a class and an object, it's not specific enough. The class for the dog could be for example the DNA that tells you how to create a dog.