# When to use an abstract class? An interface?

Tags: java, oop, interface, abstract-class

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Interface vs Abstract Class (general OO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761194/interface-vs-abstract-class-general-oo)

I am little bit familiar with the terms Abstract class and the interface.
But i want to know in which situation i have to use the interface and in which condition the abstract class.

Thanks

Comment: also possible duplicate of [Whent ouse an interface instead of an abstract class and vice versa](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/479142/when-to-use-an-interface-instead-of-an-abstract-class-and-vice-versa)

Answer (score 1):

[Interface vs Abstract Class](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/interfacevsabstract.html) should be a useful read.

In short, Abstract Classes are meant to be extended, as in you're giving someone a base to work off of. Interfaces ensure that things have a common way of interacting with one another without having to worry about the inside details.

Comment: Jeff can u give a good practical example for it.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: you can implements many `interfaces`, but can only inherit from one `class`, so if you want to inherit some logic, you should use `Abstract Class`, otherwise `Interface` is more extensible.