# C# - A class for Generic database connection, command, reader

Tags: c#, ado.net

Suppose I am designing a class that can handle any database technology to create a connection, execute command and retrieve data, etc.

If I need to create a generic database handling class for existing RDBMSs (like SQL Server, Oracle, FireBird, et.), which .net abstract-class/Interface should I use {DbConnection, DbCommand, DbParameter,...} or {IDbConnection, IDbCommand, IDbParameter,...}?

Should I use the code like

```
public bool CreateConnection(DatabaseTypeEnum type)
{
    DbConnection conn ;

    if(type==DatabaseTye.Oracle)
    {
        //....
    }    
}

public DbDataReader GetData()
{

    DbCommand comm;
    //...
}
```

or,

```
public bool CreateConnection(DatabaseTypeEnum type)
{
    IDbConnection conn ;

    if(type==DatabaseTye.Oracle)
    {
        //....
    } 
}

public IDbDataReader GetData()
{

    IDbCommand comm;
    //...
}
```

And, Why?

Comment: Are you meanig to ask: When do I need to create a generic ...? and why?

Comment: It's recommended to program using Interface and not the exact implementation. So in your codes, the 2nd option is preferred. Similar discussion has been discussed in Stack Overflow : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/570302/when-are-interfaces-needed

Comment: Be careful about the usage of the word 'Generic' when talking about C#, as it has a very specific meaning unrelated to this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ermm... totally different question :)

OK, neither...

You are going to violate Open Close Principle when you do that...  The switch / if statement in that particular place is making me uncomfortable :).

I'd leave the actual creation to a Factory class and your code should not care if it is talking to a SQL Server or DB2 or Oracle or whatever.

Ideally, your code should only talk to IDbConnection, IDbCommand, etc. or the abstract base class (DbConnection, DbCommand, etc.).  Sometimes I do find that you need to upcast to a specific provider tho (like SqlDataReader for using specific methods), but it is quite rare.

The Factory will encapsulate this switch / if statement to a single place so it's easily maintainable.  You can further abstract the actual creation in a app.config.  So in app.config you choose what type of DB backend you are supporting and the Factory will pick it up from there and create the necessary DB stuffs for you.

See: [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd0w4a2z(VS.80).aspx).  Read about Creating DbProviderFactory and Connection part...

Comment: +1 from me. In the factory I use the providerName in the connection string to map to a providerSettings for provider-specific things like parameter prefixes (e.g. "@" for MSSQL, ":" for Oracle, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use generics?

You can define your class like this for example:

```
public class DBHelper<T, Y, W> where T: DbConnection, new() where Y : DbCommand, new()
{
        private T conn_ = new T();
        private Y comm_ = new Y();            
}
```

That's what I do to and its really easy to maintain.

Comment: You dont need Y type parameter here since DbCommand can be instantiated from connection object, like conn.CreateCommand(). Also what is W type parameter for?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `IDbConnection` and `IDbCommand` since different database vendors will have different implementation of the interfaces (for their ADO.NET thing), but **better** not exactly as you have posted. You should instead make the entire class generic to support generic `IDbConnection` and `IDbCommand`. May be like this:

```
public class Db<T> where T : IDbConnection, new()
{
    public bool CreateConnection()
    {
        T conn;

        //now you dont need these lines since you dont have to worry about
        //what type of db you are using here, since they all implement
        //IDbConnection, and in your case its just T.
        //if(type==DatabaseTye.Oracle)
        //{
            //....
        //}
    }

    public DbDataReader GetData()
    {
        //get comm object from S conn
        using(var conn = new S())
            using (var comm = conn.CreateCommand())

        //...
    }
```

The benefit is that you can pass to this class the types you want to use for `DbConnection` and `DbCommand` which will be different for MySQL .net connector and Oracle one. So you have some sort of control from outside the class. You can see to this [question and my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13133804/writing-driver-class-generic-for-any-database-support) for reference for a basic implementation.