# How do you keep the value of global variables (namely a struct variable) between postbacks?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, postback

I'm new to this and have already searched for this with not much luck :(

Lets say I have defined a struct array globally and filled the array with data on an Ajax ModalPopupExtender. I then have a *ddl_SelectedIndexChanged* event that does a **postback** and seems to recycle my array.

Is there a way to fire the *ddl_SelectedIndexChanged* event to perform some code without doing a postback? Or is there an easy way to make the array of type struct retain it's values?

(I am creating a website btw)

Thanks in advance...

Comment: You could save the Array in a **session** object, or if it's page level, maybe use **ViewState** - assuming this is Webforms?

Comment: What do you mean by 'defined globally'? And you should tag it properly, because you seem to be talking about Ajax calls so I'm guessing you're creating a website. `Show us some code: !important;`

Comment: @christiandev - Yea, Webforms. I though of saving it as a session variable but it will be quick a large number of variables. I am not quite familiar with ViewState but will look it up.

Answer (score 2):

To store in session...

```
Session["ArrayName"] = ArrayVariable;
```

..to get it back into the Array type

```
var array = (ArrayType)Session["ArrayName"];
```

With viewState

```
ViewState.Add("ArrayName", ArrayVariable);
var array= (ArrayType)ViewState["ArrayName"];
```

[What is the difference between SessionState and ViewState?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733482/what-is-the-difference-between-sessionstate-and-viewstate)

If this is to be used only for the page you are on, then you should use ViewState.  If you need it to be available across the site, then your options are **Session**, **Cache** or **DB**.  Also, make sure you first check that the objects are available, as in..

```
if (Session["ArrayName"] != null)
   var array = (ArrayType)Session["ArrayName"];
```

..or you will be victim to the Object Not Set Reference error.

See this article for [*using Cache in ASP.NET*](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/334277/A-Beginner-s-Tutorial-on-Caching-in-ASP-NET).

Comment: View state is what is needed here. Session state is generally best avoided. See my previous answer about this. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/160947/should-session-variables-be-avoided

Comment: @TimRogers, I agree, that's why I also mentioned using `ViewState`

Comment: Thanks very much for the help guys, I will try some of these soon!

Answer (score 1):

You could store your array in `ViewState`, like below:

```
ViewState["arrayName"] = array;
```

where `array` is the name of your array. Then you could easily retrieve it using `ViewState["arrayName"]`. If you array is an array of strings, you could easily retrieve it like:

```
string[] arr = ViewState["arrayName"] as string[];
```

For further documenation on `ViewState` please have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If it is page level then go for viewstate

```
ViewState["arrayName"] = array;
```

and if it is to different page then it is through session.

```
Session["ArrayName"] = ArrayVariable;
```

Comment: I added some more if you want to copy and paste that too? :)

Answer (score 0):

As said already use ViewState. Create a property in the page's class and read/write to that property. Obviously change the List to what ever type your array is.

```
public List<string> SomeArray
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["SomeArray"] != null)
        {
            return (List<string>)ViewState["SomeArray"];
        }
        return null;
    }
    set { ViewState["SomeArray"] = value; }
 }
```

Really though when you bind values to a dropdown the dropdown should hold the data in viewstate itself unless your logic clears on page load. Posting your Page_Load event may identify your real issue.

**UPDATE**
Although having read your question again I could be wrong, post code!