# How to pass parameters between two onclick event

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a textbox(txtSearch) and button(search) and one link button. First I enter some name in the textbox and click the Search button(username is getting assigned) and click on the link button.

Now username parameter value is not getting passed from searchbutton_click event to linkbutton_click event? How can i achieve this?

```
public partial class Users: System.Web.UI.Page
{
     public string username = string.empty;

     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {

     }

     public void SearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         username = txtUser.Text.ToString();
     }

     protected void linkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         response.write(username) \\here username is coming as empty string.
     }
}
```

Comment: Is the page reloaded when clicking the SearchButton?

Comment: Yes. It is getting reloaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581(v=vs.100).aspx), like

```
  public string username 
  { 
     get { return Session["username"] as string; }
     set { Session["username"] = value; }
  }
```

Comment: It is working for me. Which is the best one to use? Session or Viewstate here?

Comment: @Selva Viewstate.  ViewState will function properly if the page is open in multiple tabs, Session wouldn't.

Comment: @Selva Viewstate would work only on one page, Session would work on multiple pages, see this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/733482/what-is-the-difference-between-sessionstate-and-viewstate)

Comment: your answer make sense to me. I will use session properties for my issue. Please let me know this is optimized solution for my situation?

Comment: I don't really know your situation, if you have only one page, where you use `username` you should user `ViewState`, if you need `username` on other pages - use `Session`.

Answer (score 1):

you  can use viewstate like  below.

```
public string username
{
    get { return (string)ViewState["username"]; }
    set { ViewState["username"] = value; }
}
```