# ViewState issue with asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have below code,

```
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        ViewState("ItemID") = 0
        If Not Request.QueryString("id") Is Nothing Then
            ViewState("ItemID") = Request.QueryString("id")
            ItemID = Integer.Parse(ViewState("ItemID"))
        End If
        If ItemID > 0 Then
            ltrTitle.Text = "Edit Item"
            bindEditData()
        End If
    End If
```

When I tried to get `ViewState("ItemID")` on button click, it returns nothing. Any help?

Comment: Are you intentionally using ViewState instead of Session? [What is the difference between SessionState and ViewState?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/733486/1115360)

Comment: Could you give us more information, for example: where this code is used,  the body of bindEditData and the body of button click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you have your code in not postback method. So once your page postback, viewstate value will be lost.

Please change your code to,

```
ViewState("ItemID") = 0
If Not Request.QueryString("id") Is Nothing Then
    ViewState("ItemID") = Request.QueryString("id")
    ItemID = Integer.Parse(ViewState("ItemID"))
End If
If Not Page.IsPostBack Then        
    If ItemID > 0 Then
        ltrTitle.Text = "Edit Item"
        bindEditData()
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

The ViewState is probably turned off on your page. The `EnableViewState` attribute is set to `false` or the `ViewStateMode` attribute is set to `Disabled`:

```
<%@ Page EnableViewState="false" ... />
<%@ Page ViewStateMode="Disabled" ... />
```

You can enable the ViewState by changing these settings:

```
<%@ Page EnableViewState="true" ... />
<%@ Page ViewStateMode="Enabled" ... />
```

These are the default settings, and are necessary only if the ViewState is disabled at the application level (in Web.config).